# Synchronizing multiple graphs using nvd3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, dom-events

I have 2 basic line graphs on a page that share the same X axis.  What I am trying to accomplish is syncing these graphs up so that when hovering over a point on one graph, the same hover event is triggered on the second graph.

So far I have figured out how to listen into the event via:

```
chart.lines.dispatch.on('elementMouseover.tooltip', function(e) {
    // Need to trigger same event on the xAxis of a separate graph
});
```

digging thru the nvd3 and d3 source code hasn't brought any revelation onto how to accomplish this so far.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work I guess.

```
chart1.lines.dispatch.on('customEvent', chart2.lines.dispatch.customEvent);
```